# Is this TestNG IRetryListener expected behavior or a Known Bug?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created a simple test using selenium webdriver with two test Methods *verifyLoginPageText* and *verifyForgotPasswordPage* by implementing **'IRetryAnalyzer'**. We are re-running only 'verifyForgotPasswordPage' if fails for the second time.

Test 'verifyForgotPasswordPage' failed for the first attempt and passed in next attempt. And test 'verifyLoginPageText' got fail due to some error.

**In the console it has shown as below:**

[image]

When we view in 'Results of Running Suite' under 'All Tests' and 'Failed Tests', Passed test 'verifyForgotPasswordPage' is showing as Failed in 'Failed Tests' But the same is showing as Passed under All Tests.

Please find the below two screen shots:

**Here is the image for 'All Tests' :**

[image]

**Here is the image for 'Failed Tests' :**

[image]

Please clarify.

Comment: Duration mentioned against them will give u ur answer i guess so...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the failed results...these links should help
[TestNG retrying failed tests doesn't output the correct test results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131912/testng-retrying-failed-tests-doesnt-output-the-correct-test-results)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/testng-users/s_8HeT4en9s/wE7qDmYV-0oJ