# Remove (duplicate) failed TestNG result via test listener

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

Similar to the solution posted here [TestNG retrying failed tests doesn't output the correct test results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131912/testng-retrying-failed-tests-doesnt-output-the-correct-test-results), I'm trying to remove a (duplicate) test result using a test listener during onFinish(ITestContext context).

Although the removal of the result with context.getFailedTests().removeResult(result) appears to work fine (the result actually is removed), there seems to be "some other spot" where the results are being pulled from cause the build still fails.

Also note that when I run the sample test from the article above (which has one duplicate failure to be removed and one passed test), I get a difference in "test results" (not cleaned up as expected) vs. "suite results" (duplicate failure removed as expected).

And, where is the reporting pulling the results from to decide whether to fail the build? Or is it just that it's pulling the results before I'm cleaning up the failed tests ... ?

```
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0  
===============================================
```

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, we're running those tests with maven, and they are ITs, so we run them with the failsafe plugin. The problem is that even though it appears that the tests are removed, mvn verify still fails the build as it considers build failures to be found regardless.

And also if run such a test from Eclipse, even though the tests are removed, failures are still being printed in the log when the suite finishes.

**About RetryAnalyzer:** I would not consider using RetryAnalyzer good/best practice at all, but if you find yourself in a situation where you need to solve the problem, e.g. you inherited a test suite that is relying on RetryAnalyzer, you may find this useful.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem in between?

Comment: We sort of figured out something"usable", although not what I ultimately wanted. I will try to find some time in the next few days to clean up the code and post it.

Comment: Eager to see your solution!

Comment: Sorry, took way longer than I promised, but our solution is below. If you have any questions, please post them below.

Comment: Ha! Hold on! I just realized that the other solution in the other TestNG thread is actually ... yours! Well ... anyhow, the main thing that I changed is that we're running mvn integration-test and trust the TestNG plugin to fail the run if necessary based on the TestNG result file. Clean up will be useless if you do try it with mvn verify

Answer (score 4):

Try using this code:

**ListenerApadter**:

```
public class MyTestListenerAdapter extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer() != null) {
            MyRetryAnalyzer retryAnalyzer = (MyRetryAnalyzer)result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer();

            if(retryAnalyzer.isRetryAvailable()) {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
            } else {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
            }
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
        }
    }

   @Overrride
   public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
     Iterator<ITestResult> failedTestCases =context.getFailedTests().getAllResults().iterator();
    while (failedTestCases.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("failedTestCases");
        ITestResult failedTestCase = failedTestCases.next();
        ITestNGMethod method = failedTestCase.getMethod();
        if (context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
            System.out.println("failed test case remove as dup:" + failedTestCase.getTestClass().toString());
            failedTestCases.remove();
        } else {

            if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("failed test case remove as pass retry:" + failedTestCase.getTestClass().toString());
                failedTestCases.remove();
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

**RetryAnalizer**:

```
public class MyRetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private static int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;

    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(MAX_RETRY_COUNT);

    public boolean isRetryAvailable() {
        return (count.intValue() > 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        boolean retry = false;
        if (isRetryAvailable()) {
            System.out.println("Going to retry test case: " + result.getMethod() + ", " + (MAX_RETRY_COUNT - count.intValue() + 1) + " out of " + MAX_RETRY_COUNT);
            retry = true;
            count.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return retry;
    }
}
```

**POM.xml -> Surefire Configuration:**

This is where you should configure "overwrite" surefire listener wich has their own counters.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles><suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile></suiteXmlFiles>
 <properties> 
   <property>
    <name>listener</name>
    <value>Utils.MyTestListenerAdapter,Utils.MyRetryAnalizer</value>
   </property>
 </properties>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this is not going to work reliably. First of all, we consider test runs with skips as not successful. Second, the solution seems a bit risky, as not every RetryAnalyzer might be of that type (maybe in smaller projects, but not in bigger projects spanning multiple maven projects). The idea with the Reporter.setCurrentStatus() seems interesting though.  Also, on a side note: This type of RetryAnalyzer solution does not work properly for test methods with parameters / data providers.

Comment: @mac Updated: Add code to "onFinish" to handle the way you need skipped and failed tests

Comment: in general, I think you have now some contradictions in your code as you're marking the test as a skip, but then you're removing failures later on. Also, I think you could just move the whole part that you have in onTestFailure() into the RetryAnalyzer itself, and you then also wouldn't have to do the risky casting. In general though, I think that's still the same approach as in the link that I posted at the top. The point is however that when you do all of that, I believe the mvn verify phase (cause we're actually doing this for ITs with failsafe not surefire) will still fail the build

Comment: Is there an approach when we are running Test methods through data provider, because int this case, we would anyway have multiple result objects for a one method?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going for a solution that uses a suite listener.

The solution may not fully clean up what TestNG / your tests log to the console, but if you use the TestNG Jenkins plugin, and had a failure first on every test, and then success, the test run ends up to be green, which I guess is the most important thing.

And yes, we run **mvn integration-test** (not mvn verify) and let the TestNG plugin deal with pass / fail. [The solution is quite similar / builds on what was posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131912/testng-retrying-failed-tests-doesnt-output-the-correct-test-results).

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.ITestContext;

/**
 * {@link ISuiteListener} implementation to clean up duplicate test results caused by retrying tests using the
 * {@link RetryAnalyzer}
 */
public class SuiteResultListener implements ISuiteListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
        LOG.info("Cleaning up duplicate test failures in suite '" + suite.getName() + "' ...");
        final Map<String, ISuiteResult> results = suite.getResults();
        int removedFailures = 0;
        for (ISuiteResult result : results.values()) {
            final ITestContext testContext = result.getTestContext();

            removedFailures += TestListenerUtil.cleanUpDuplicateFailures(testContext);
        }

        LOG.info("Removed " + removedFailures + " duplicate test failure(s) from suite '" + suite.getName() + "'");
    }
}
```

And here's the magic that happens in the TestListenerUtil class:

```
public static int cleanUpDuplicateFailures(ITestContext testContext) {
    final String testContextName = testContext.getName();
    int removedFailures = 0;

    LOG.info("Cleaning up failures in test context '" + testContextName + "' ...");
    final Set<ITestResult> failedTests = testContext.getFailedTests().getAllResults();
    if (failedTests.isEmpty()) {
        LOG.info("There are no failures in test context '" + testContextName + "'\n");
    } else {
        // collect all id's from passed test
        final Set<Integer> passedTestIds = new HashSet<>();
        final Set<ITestResult> passedTests = testContext.getPassedTests().getAllResults();
        LOG.info("Analyzing " + passedTests.size() + " passed test(s)");
        for (ITestResult result : passedTests) {
            final int testId = TestListenerUtil.getId(result);
            passedTestIds.add(testId);
            LOG.info("  Passed test " + TestListenerUtil.getName(result) + ": #" + testId + " @ "
                    + getStartTime(result));
        }

        // check which failed test results should be removed
        final List<Integer> resultsToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
        final Set<Integer> failedTestIds = new HashSet<>();

        LOG.info("Analyzing " + failedTests.size() + " failed test(s)");
        for (ITestResult result : failedTests) {
            final int testId = TestListenerUtil.getId(result);
            final String name = TestListenerUtil.getName(result);

            // if we saw this test pass or fail before we mark the result for deletion
            if (failedTestIds.contains(testId) || passedTestIds.contains(testId)) {
                LOG.info("  Adding test " + name + " to be removed: #" + testId + " @ " + getStartTime(result));
                resultsToBeRemoved.add(testId);
            } else {
                LOG.info("  Remembering failed test " + name + ": #" + testId + " @ " + getStartTime(result));
                failedTestIds.add(testId);
            }
        }

        // finally delete all duplicate failures (if any)
        final int duplicateFailures = resultsToBeRemoved.size();
        if (duplicateFailures > 0) {
            LOG.info("Cleaning up failed tests (expecting to remove " + resultsToBeRemoved.size()
                    + " result(s)) ...");
            for (ITestResult result : testContext.getFailedTests().getAllResults()) {
                final int testId = TestListenerUtil.getId(result);
                final String info = TestListenerUtil.getName(result) + ": #" + testId + " @ "
                        + getStartTime(result);
                if (resultsToBeRemoved.contains(testId)) {
                    LOG.info("  Removing failed test result " + info);
                    testContext.getFailedTests().removeResult(result);
                    resultsToBeRemoved.remove((Integer) testId);
                    removedFailures++;
                } else {
                    LOG.info("  Not removing failed test result " + info);
                }
            }
        }

        if (removedFailures == duplicateFailures) {
            LOG.info("Removed " + removedFailures + " failed test result(s) in '" + testContextName + "'\n");
        } else {
            LOG.warn("Removed " + removedFailures + " failed test result(s) in '" + testContextName
                    + "' (expected to remove " + duplicateFailures + ")\n");
        }
    }

    return removedFailures;
}
```

With those two additional utils methods:

```
public static String getName(ITestResult result) {
    final List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    if (result.getParameters() != null) {
        for (Object parameter : result.getParameters()) {
            if (parameter instanceof TestResult && ((TestResult) parameter).getStatus() < 0) {
                // TestResult.toString() will explode with status < 0, can't use the toString() method
                parameters.add(parameter.getClass().getName() + "@" + parameter.hashCode());
            } else {
                parameters.add(parameter == null ? "null" : parameter.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    return result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getSimpleName() + "." + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "("
            + StringUtils.join(parameters, ",") + ")";
}

public static int getId(ITestResult result) {
    final HashCodeBuilder builder = new HashCodeBuilder();
    builder.append(result.getTestClass().getRealClass());
    builder.append(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
    builder.append(result.getParameters());
    return builder.toHashCode();
}
```

And also, if you're interested how our RetryAnalyzer works, see below.

One thing that is important to understand, is that we're taking the the parameters of the test method into account in both the RetryAnalyzer and the duplicate result clean up. Those are relevant cause we often work with DataProviders.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();

    private static Integer maxRetries;
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> retryCount = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        // only re-try failures
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            final String testName = TestListenerUtil.getName(result);
            final int count = getRetryCount(result);
            final int maxRetriesAllowed = getMaxRetriesAllowed();
            if (count < maxRetriesAllowed) {
                retryCount.put(TestListenerUtil.getId(result), count + 1);
                LOG.info("Retrying test (attempt " + (count + 1) + "/" + maxRetriesAllowed + "): " + testName);
                return true;
            } else {
                LOG.error("Failing test after " + count + " retries: " + testName);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean canRetry(ITestResult result) {
        return result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE && getRetryCount(result) < getMaxRetriesAllowed();
    }

    private int getRetryCount(ITestResult result) {
        final int testId = TestListenerUtil.getId(result);
        return retryCount.containsKey(testId) ? retryCount.get(testId) : 0;
    }

    public static int getMaxRetriesAllowed() {
        return maxRetries == null ? Config.MAX_TEST_RETRIES : maxRetries;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm back on the issue. Just realized that testng changed the behaviour in 6.9.5! Tests that are being retried will be set to skipped now. See  https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/878. That would make any TestListener that removes failed Tests obsolete.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree: I think you will then want to remove the skipped ones still. But, great to know that this changes in 6.9.5! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below code

```
   @AfterTest
public void afterTest(ITestContext context) {
       Set<ITestResult> passedTests = context.getPassedTests().getAllResults();
       passedTests.forEach(i -> {
           if (context.getFailedTests().getAllMethods().contains(i.getMethod())) {
               context.getFailedTests().getAllMethods().remove(i.getMethod());
           }
        });
}
```